# Check and remove new line character('enter') in between a record in csv file(changes to be reflected in csv as well) using shell

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, newline

My file looks like-

```
Number,File_Name,Date,Owner_Name,ID
-1,"ABCD",23/12/2016,badf hbdf,234
2,"CSVD",23/12/2017,grfsg
sffs
fsg
sgd,456
-3,"ERTG
DF
YUO",23/09/2019,ndf
sdg
dsg,
276
4,"TYU YOOU",23/05/2016,fd fg dg
```

I'm unable to remove new line characters in between one record using shell/awk script.

this csv file **can** contain

1. any number of columns
2. newline characters in between new column and can occur more than one once in one record.
3. Solution should be reflected in csv and not on just output window.
4. First column can contain such data **-1,-3** as well.
5. Columns doesn't necessarily have double quotes around them.

Right now I'm using solution based on awk but it doesn't correct my csv file but only prints in the output window and cannot handle **-1,-3** in first line (it's combining 1st and 2nd line due to this **-** character).

```
awk '/^$/{next} {val=$0 ~ /^[0-9]/?(val?val ORS $0:$0):(val?val OFS $0:$0)} END{print val}' file.csv
```

Comment: Update the question with your expected output

Comment: Allow for a leading `-` in your regex `^-?[0-9]`; redirect the output to a file (appending `> newname.csv` to the command). Check newname.csv and `mv newname.csv file.csv` if correct.

Comment: What condition should I add if a file can start with a string (or string with double quotes ) or number as well ? Right now my solution is not working fine if there is string at 1st column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually better to use dedicated CSV parser for complex csv modifications.

HOwever for your requirements, this `perl` script may work:

```
perl -i -0777 -pe 's/((?:,"|(?!^)\G)[^",\n]*)\n/\1/g; s/,\n/,/' file.csv

cat file.csv
```

**output:**

```
Number,File_Name,Date,Owner_Name,ID
-1,"ABCD",23/12/2016,"badf hbdf",234
2,"CSVD",23/12/2017,"grfsgsffsfsgsgd",456
-3,"ERTGDFYUO","23/09/2019,"ndfsdgdsg,276
4,"TYU YOOU",23/05/2016,"fd fg dg"
```

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match.

Comment: One extra condition I forgot to include - what if column doesnot contain double quotes and newline character converts to a space. then what'll be the solution ?

Comment: There was no double quote before `276` and this solution took care of that also.

Comment: Also don't provide new requirements in comments. If there is anything to add then edit your question with example input & output data.